Buildable libraries cannot import or export from non-buildable librarieseslint@nx/enforce-module-boundaries
I am working with an Angular monorepo using Nx, and I've run into an issue while trying to build a component library that's set up to be publishable to npm. My project structure is as follows:
nx-monorepo-root
│
├── /apps
│  ├── /app1
│  └── /app2
│
├── /libs
│  ├── /shared-ui-lib
│  ├── /app1Lib
│  ├── /app2Lib
│  ├── /prime-ng-lib
│
├── /package
│  └── /component-lib
│
├── /tools
│
├── /node_modules
│
├── /dist
│
├── nx.json
├── workspace.json
├── tsconfig.base.json

I've created a buildable component library (component-lib) that I want to publish to npm. This library also depends on another library (prime-ng-lib) that wraps PrimeNG components.
Here's the relevant code for component-lib:
// Import statements
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Button1Component } from './button1/button1.component';
import { PrimeNgLibModule } from '@monorepov2/prime-ng-lib'; // Importing the PrimeNG wrapper module

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, PrimeNgLibModule],
  declarations: [Button1Component],
  exports: [Button1Component]
})
export class G99UiLibModule {}

But when I try to import primeNgLibrary module in component lib I am getting below error which is fixed if I add eslint disable rule
Buildable libraries cannot import or export from non-buildable libraries eslint@nx/enforce-module-boundaries
When I try to build component-lib, I encounter the following error:

PS C:\Users\Desktop\Workspace\Learning\Angular\g99\monorepov2> npx nx build g99-ui-lib

> nx run g99-ui-lib:build:production

Building Angular Package

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point 'g99-ui-lib'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.
✖ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.
 NX   Cannot destructure property 'pos' of 'file.referencedFiles[index]' as it is undefined.
Pass --verbose to see the stacktrace.

Additionally, when I remove the dependency on prime-ng-lib, the build process works fine. The code also works as expected when running locally.
Questions:

How can I resolve the issue of building a buildable library (component-lib) that depends on a non-buildable library (prime-ng-lib) in an Nx workspace?

Are there any recommended solutions or best practices for handling dependencies between buildable and non-buildable libraries in Nx?


**Additional Information:
I've tried using the --verbose flag but didn't find much detail in the stack trace.
My Nx and Angular versions are up-to-date.

I am also facing the same issue, still no solution.
This is still a open issue on https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/4829

This is one of the real pain point working with nx
